# Getting information about descriptor

Tags: linux

let's assume that my process accepted a connection and its `descriptor = 1024.`
Now, I would like to get information about that socket, for example about client port.

Is it possible to ask Linux about that having only descriptor?

Comment: Do you mean _file descriptor_ ?

Comment: yes I do :) :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting client address and port, you can use [getpeername()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html):

```
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(peer_addr);

if (getpeername(descriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_addr, &len) == -1)
{
     // TODO: error handling
}
```

Information of own end address can be aquired by using [getsockname()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html).